# Numerical Analysis - Jacobian of matrices of "complicated " functions

Tags: multivariable-calculus, numerical-methods

I want to use Newton's method in order to solve an equation, which has the following term in it (I want to solve it in one-dimension first, so we can assume every "gradient" is actually a first-order derivative):
$$
\nabla \cdot \left( f(1-f)\nabla f  \right) 
$$
assume $D_1 $ is the differentiation matrix of order 1 and write this expression as:
$$
D1 \cdot \left( f(1-f) D1  f  \right) 
$$

Now, in order to use Newton's method, I need to calculate the Jacobian of this expression wrt $f$ and I have no idea how to do it.

What I do know is that:
$$
J(f(1-f) )= diag(1-2f)
$$
and:
$$
J(D1 f ) = D1 
$$

But, does this help me in any sense when trying to find the Jacobian of the complicated expression above?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume your whole equation is 
$$
∇⋅(f(1−f)∇f)=g
$$
Given some approximation $f$ you want to compute the Newton step $s$ so that $f+s$ solves the equation up to errors $O(\|s\|^2)$. Extracting the linear factors in $s$ gives
$$
∇⋅([f(1−f)+(1-2f)s]∇(f+s))+O(\|s\|^2)
\\
=∇⋅(f(1−f)∇f)+∇⋅((1-2f)s∇f+f(1−f)∇s)+O(\|s\|^2)
$$
Thus you would get to solve 
$$
∇⋅((1-2f)∇f·s+f(1−f)∇s) = g-∇⋅(f(1−f)∇f)
$$